# minikube does not start with KVM driver

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, cluster-computing, minikube

I can't run minikube with KVM driver on Ubuntu:16.04. I receive the next error
[image]

If you have any recommendations, please, let me know. Thank you!!!

Comment: I have a different issue.  But maybe my install steps could help you.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46141643/what-starts-my-minikube

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try KVM2 driver?  at least you can open issue to minikube team if there is any problem.

https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/master/docs/drivers.md

> The KVM2 driver is intended to replace KVM driver. The KVM2 driver is
>   maintained by the minikube team, and is built, tested and released
>   with minikube.

Thanks.

BR/
Robert

Comment: "Thanks"? for what?... mind clarifying that (and perhaps enhancing your answer)